# Use of "ever" instead of "more and more"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, adverbs

I wonder if I can use "ever" in place of "more and more". 
For example, do the following two sentences have the same meaning?

> - Software is getting more and more complex.
> - Software is getting ever complex.

Comment: While your premise is correct, the example seems a bit odd. Consider: 'Software is becoming ever so complex.'

Comment: Why is this getting close votes? The question seems clear.

Comment: @Matt: My closevote is because it's general reference that *ever* doesn't mean *more and more*. Personally I didn't read OP's erroneous second example as missing the word *"so"* - I saw it as missing the word *"more"*.

Comment: Reference for the meanings of [ever](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ever?s=t). The meaning of [more and more](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/more) is definition 10.

Answer (score 1):

As Kris notes, you should say "getting ever so complex" rather than "ever complex".

But that said, why? "ever so" is a pretty archaic phrase. Frankly, if you use it, you'll sound like a 90-year-old lady.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly literary but it's fine in formal writing.

Comment: I don't get this. Are you seriously suggesting that *"Software is getting ever complex"* could ever be spoken/written by a competent native speaker?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "Software is getting ever **more** complex" or "Software is getting more and more complex" as being more correct. Your latter example sounds awkward/wrong.

Comment: Or even, "increasingly complex".